# Got this error while git was Collecting jinja?

Tags: python

When I try to put my put my code in Heroku, I get the following error:

```
    Collecting jinja
remote:          Downloading Jinja-1.2.tar.gz (252 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jinja (from versions: 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for jinja
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I have installed jinja2, but I think is using an older version. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you need `jinja2` you should add `jinja2` to your `requirements.txt`, not `jinja`.

Comment: @Selcuk that tricks me like every time I start a new project using it haha

Comment: @flakes They considered [renaming it back to `jinja`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66163) but it hasn't happened.

Comment: @Selcuk *"The next version will be Jinja2 2.11, followed by Jinja2 3.0"* that is too funny. We have a similar problem with one of our internal packages, just having a name that no longer really reflects it's responsibilities. Refactoring names like this when you have to manage it across a larger distribution of projects is tough stuff.